# Is it really a good idea to revert privileges from people who already gained them?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation, moderation

The community seems to have been doing a good job in keeping the questions on-topic around here. I have helped, and have enjoyed being part of it. However, now that Programmers is out of beta, I no longer have the privileges I had.

I'm not trying to whine, I am just wondering if it makes sense to revert all previously gained privileges? In the meantime, the burden has increased for those who retained their privileges.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a question for [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com): all sites that leave beta have the same behavior. Frankly, killing the ability for people < 3,000 rep to vote to reopen is the best thing that can happen to this site.

Comment: @Mark: that is a good point, the ping pong is silly.

Comment: @Mark, The problem is losing the vote to close.

Comment: @Lance: but in balance, is better now :-) But this joy will last little.

Comment: Would an alternative be to make (some) of those people moderators until more can be appointed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see

[Can we grandfather in rep abilities as sites leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta)

TL;DR version -- reputation levels need to be the same across the network.

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the answer and link.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

In beta you want to demonstrate a very active self-moderating community. Out of beta you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers doesn't seem to have a big problem; there are enough users here above 3k that we can effectively police ourselves.

Answer (score -3):

I feel bad as I lose the editing privilege.